# Discrete Math: Multiplying a set by ∅

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

How would you multiply any set by  $\varnothing$? Lets say $A \times \varnothing$. Would that simply be equal to  $\varnothing$? or Would I write out $(a,  \varnothing ), (a_1,  \varnothing), (a_2,  \varnothing)$ etc. If possible could you explain your answer in words or short proof?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$(a, \varnothing ), (a1, \varnothing), (a2, \varnothing) $ are elements of $A\times \{\varnothing \}$. If $(a,x) \in A\times \varnothing$ then $a \in A$ and $x \in \varnothing$. But there is no $x \in \varnothing$, so there is no $(a,x) \in A\times \varnothing$. So $A\times \varnothing$ is empty, which means $A\times \varnothing=\varnothing$.

Comment: Thank you miracle! Keep working those wonders :)

Answer (score 0):

By definition, $\forall x: x\notin \varnothing$ and $\forall x,y:[(x,y)\in A\times\varnothing \iff x\in A \land y\in\varnothing]$.

Suppose $(a,b)\in A\times\varnothing$. Then $b\in\varnothing$, leading to a contradiction. Therefore, $\forall x, y:[(x,y)\notin A\times\varnothing],$ i.e. $A\times \varnothing$ is empty.